# can we popop the name of the place when we use addGeoJson in R

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

I'm using addgeoJson function for the india map. I have data that I got it from here
https://gadm.org/download_country.html

for example I'm using this data

This is a json file and I read that json file and pass it to addGeoJson function.

```
library(jsonlite) 
library(leaflet)  
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle-boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"
geojson <- fromJSON(url, simplifyVector = FALSE) 
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addGeoJSON(geojson) %>% 
  setView(lng = -122.2, lat = 47.6, zoom = 10)
```

So I need to popup the names when I click on a particular state or city here. It should give some information when we click on it.

Is this possible to do it? and how?

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for is stored deep in the structure of a geojson file (list). See for instance the first object of your dataset

```
geojson$features[[1]]$properties
```

Luckily there is a easier way to deal with it.

Use the package `leaflet.extra`, function `addGeoJSONv2` specifying your label under argument `popupProperty`

```
 library(leaflet.extras)
 library(jsonlite) 
 library(leaflet)  
 
 url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle- 
 boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"
 geojson_fil <- fromJSON(url, simplifyVector = FALSE) 
  
 leaflet() %>% 
 addTiles() %>% 
 setView(lng = -122.2, lat = 47.6, zoom = 10)  %>% 
 addGeoJSONv2(geojson_fil, 
              popupProperty = 'ZCTA5CE10')
```